# Cut option in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
<select>
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=1>2</option>
  <option value=1>3</option>
  ...
  <option value=97>97</option>
  <option value=98>98</option>
  <option value=99>99</option>
</select>
```

How can i with jQuery cut with this all option from value 20 to 40?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var select = $('#mySelect');

for (var i = 20; i <= 40; i++)
{
    select.find('option[value="' + i + '"]').remove();
}
```

The simpliest way...

Another is `filter()`, here:

```
$('#mySelect option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() >= 20 && $(this).val() <= 40;
}).remove();
```

Comment: The first solution would definetely be more efficient. For the second, you could just use `this.value` as "this" is an HtmlOptionElement in this case, to accelarate it a bit.